# Ruby Module Constant Set and Read

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm developing a module that contains standard methods as well as CLI (Thor) and API (Sinatra). I've created a Submodule that includes a class that inherits Sinatra::Base:

```
module Monteverde
  module Activity
    def self.version
      "1.0.1"
    end

    class API < Sinatra::Base
      set :port, 22340
      get "/version" do
        Monteverde::Activity.version
      end
      run! if defined? Monteverde::OPERATION
    end
  end
end
```

This "Activity" is invokes from the CLI (Thor):

```
module Monteverde
  class CLI < Thor
    desc "api", "Start Activity API"
    def api
      Monteverde.const_set("OPERATION", "started")
      Monteverde::Activity::API
    end

    desc "aversion", "Get Activity Version"
    def aversion
      puts Monteverde::Activity.version
    end
  end
end
```

If I don't add an "if" to Sinatra's run! it will run automatically and take over the rest of the methods in the module:

```
...
class API < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::DefaultRoutes
  set :port, 22340
  get "/version" do
    Monteverde::Activity.version
  end
  run!
end

$ ruby monteverde.rb aversion
$ == Sinatra (v2.0.0) has taken the stage on 22340 for development with backup from Puma
$ ...
```

My issue is that the OPERATION constant is not recognized even though it's set right before the module is called.

Why isn't OPERATION being recognized and how can I get it to be? 
Is there another more intuitive/useful way to get Sinatra not to fire when I call the module?

Comment: Would more explicit `Monteverde.const_defined? "OPERATION"` work?

Comment: The problem is that the constant isn't recognized when the API class is inherited by Sinatra::Base. I need to find a way to include external variables/constants inside of the API class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your API class definition, the `run!` line happens as soon as you require that file. It doesn't run again if you reference the class, as you're trying to do with the last line of your `def api` method.

To get around this, you can move the `run!` command into a method, and call that from Thor:

```
class API < Sinatra::Base
  # ... other stuff
  def self.start
    run! if defined? Monteverde::OPERATION
  end
end
```

Then in the Thor file:

```
 def api
   Monteverde.const_set("OPERATION", "started")
   Monteverde::Activity::API.start
 end
```

You can deduce that `run!` is a class method since it's callable in the scope of the class *definition* (not in an instance method), and so I define a class method to call it.

It would be simpler, though, to not define `def self.start`, and instead just call the `run!` method from the Thor file directly:

```
def api
  Monteverde::Activity::API.run!
end
```

Comment: Great answer! I never considered it would be as simple as calling run! directly.